# how show the database data in add/edit/form as label in jqgrid

Tags: php, mysql, forms, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

i want to display data from database as label in the add/edit form in jqgrid.

see for example: To add data to jqgrid we will click on the + icon. A popup will be opened for data entry. text boxes or checkboxes can be displayed in the given examples of jqgrid. but i want to display a label in that add/edit popup form.

Is there any in built functionality in jqgrid like

To display a checkbox in the add/edit popup form we will will specify the below code.

```
$col = array();
$col["title"] = "Closed";
$col["name"] = "closed";
$col["width"] = "50";
$col["editable"] = true;
$col["edittype"] = "checkbox"; // render as checkbox
$col["editoptions"] = array("value"=>"Yes:No"); // with these values "checked_value:unchecked_value"
$cols[] = $col;
```

the above col option will display checkbox... in the same way i want to display data in a label

Comment: You need to clarify you question a bit more..

Comment: plz check the question again i have described my question @slacker

Comment: Why do you want a label there? You want an input control don't you?

Comment: i want to display data say for example customername: john,
it should not be in editable when we click on edit form.we need to show the customer name in the edit form, but wen we click on add form it should be data entry field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$col = array();
$col["title"] = "cname";
$col["name"] = "cname";
$col["width"] = "50";
$col["editable"] = false;
$col["edittype"] = "textbox"; 

$cols[] = $col;
```

Comment: not working. empty field is displaying without any data with field name when clicking on edit